# Why isn't my servo turning on keypress using an Arduino, Arduino IDE and Processing?

Tags: arduino, processing

I stole some code from here, http://www.instructables.com/id/Overview/?ALLSTEPS and modified it heavily to try and control my servo's movement using my keyboard! The goal being I will be able to control two servos using the WASD keys.

Anywho, I am trying to use the D and A keys to control rotation of one servo. I use the following Arduino code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servoMain; // Define our Servo

void setup()
{
   servoMain.attach(10); // servo on digital pin 10
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

int v = 90;

void loop()
{
   char ch = Serial.read(); // Reads serial input
   if (Serial.available()) {
     switch(ch) {
       case 'a':
         v = v + 1;
       case 'd':
         v = v - 1;
     }
   }
   servoMain.write(v);  // Turn servo to position designated by V variable.
   delay(100);          // Wait .1 second
}
```

So basically I setup the serial connection, setup servo controls, vars, etc. Then I try to read the keyPresses sent by the following Processing code and try to attempt in moving the servo one way or another based on the key value pressed. Here's that Processing code.

```
//Processing code:
import processing.serial.*;       
Serial port; // The serial port we will be using
int r,g,b;

void setup()
{
  println(Serial.list()); // List COM-ports (AUTHORS NOTE, I am not sure what this line is all about, I've never seen this pop up when I run the Processing code? Do I need it?)
  //select second com-port from the list (COM3 for my device)
  // You will want to change the [1] to select the correct device
  // Remember the list starts at [0] for the first option.
  port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
  // I need something to focus my cursor on so Processing can capture my keystrokes!
  size (600,600);
  r = 0;
  g = 0;
  b = 0;
}

void draw()
{
  background(r,g,b);
}
void keyPressed()
{
  switch (key) {
    //Send pressed key to serial conn.
    case 'a':
      port.write(key);
      break;
    case 'd':
      port.write(key);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

When I press keys, the RX LED light on my Arduino lights up! So something must be making it somewhere, but the Servo doesn't do anything at all. Anyone know how to make my script work so my Arduino will spin the Servo one way or another based on the press of either the A or D keys?

Thanks so much!

Comment: are you able to get the servo to do anything if you don't make it wait for the keypress? Are you certain your circuit is right?

Comment: Some steps I'd recommend for testing where your issue is: 
1) take your servo out and see if you can light up an LED on keypress.
2) write directly to your servo without key input to make sure your circuit is properly hooked up. if you've got a picture or even circuit diagram, I think you can upload it to show us.
3)go more dramatic than 1 degree up or down. Your problem may be that you're only moving one degree on keypress and not again. to go from 90 to 0, you have to press 'd' 90 times. Is that what you meant to happen?

Comment: @eriese I had a simple circuit (same wiring, same PINs) and I was able to move the Servo without issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
char ch = Serial.read(); // Reads serial input
if (Serial.available()) {
  switch(ch) {
    case 'a':
      v = v + 1;
    case 'd':
      v = v - 1;
}
```

The fact is that FIRST you read a char from the buffer THAN you call the function Serial.available(). At this point you already read from the buffer and so it returns 0. You need to call Serial.available() BEFORE reading something. Sure you see the rx pin blinking, but the id statement is FALSE because the buffer is empty.

You forgot also to put break in the switch case statement

try this:

```
if (Serial.available()) {
    char ch = Serial.read(); // Reads serial input
    switch(ch) {
        case 'a':
          v = v + 1;
          break;
        case 'd':
          v = v - 1;
          break;
    }
}
```

this code works for me (i don't have a servo, sorry):

```
void setup()
{
   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

int v = 0;

void loop()
{
   if (Serial.available()) {
    char ch = Serial.read();
      switch(ch) {
        case 'a':
          v = 1;
          break;
        case 'd':
          v = 0;
          break;
      }
   }
   digitalWrite(13, v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome input @GiulioG - I'm definitely going to try this when I get home this evening, thanks again! I will report back :)

Comment: Took awhile to get back to ya, made the switch, AND IT TOTALLY WORKS! This is very exciting progress :) Thank you so much for your advice!